# HTTP Post method in GTK+

Tags: json, gtk, http-post

Recently, I'm building an application this must request to server to get data from this. I use  GTK+ to coding.

I search in the internet many times. but I don't get result i can use. So anyone can taught me how to request to server by json to get data from server

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Libsoup, it does what you want and integrates with GLib and GTK. [Here](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/libsoup-client-howto.html) is a tutorial that explains how to use it and how to do a HTTP POST.